# App freezes during internet operation httpclient or HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, httpclient, httpurlconnection

My app has a widget. I use HttpURLConnection to download content (auto download every 15 mins). It usually takes 10 seconds to download content.

Problem is while the app is in use, it freezes/hangs while this update operation goes on in the background. I am using a handler.postDelayed from updateAppWidget method from my widget class. Even though I am using a background thread, the app temporarily freezes. I thought maybe httpConn.connect(); could be the issue and used DefaultHttpClient. Still the same freeze effect.

Could someone please provide some insight to this problem?

Thanks...

from widget class using this handler...

Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

```
   public void run() {

    //download and update widget UI here.....   

   }
```

}, 1000);

```
private String download1(String urlString) {

InputStream in = null;
byte[] data = null;
URLConnection conn = null;
try
 {
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    conn = url.openConnection();

    if ((conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
    {
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        httpConn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        httpConn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect();

        if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            in = httpConn.getInputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int c;
            while((c = in.read()) > -1){
                        baos.write(c);
        }
                    data = baos.toByteArray();
                    baos.close();
                    in.close();
                    String str = new String(data);
                    System.out.println(str);
                    httpConn.disconnect();
                    ((HttpURLConnection) conn).disconnect();
                    return str;
        }
        else
            {
                    httpConn.disconnect();
                    ((HttpURLConnection) conn).disconnect();
            return("Error: Invalid data");
    }


    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.e("TAG",ex.getMessage().toString());
    return("Error: No connection");
}
finally
{
    try
    {
        if (conn != null)
        {
            conn = null;
        }
        if (in != null)
        {
            in.close();
            in = null;
        }

    }catch(IOException ex)
    {
        return("Error: "+ex.getMessage());
    }
}
return null;
```

}

Comment: How are you calling `download1()`?

Comment: added the handler call... can you please point some suggestions. The reason I used postdelayed is I thought it needs to run on UI thread to update the widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `handler.postDelayed`, the `Runnable` that you post will run on the UI thread. You need to create a `Thread` (or an `AsyncTask`, or a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, etc.) to get the network activity off the UI thread.

Without seeing your code, it's hard to offer specific advice about how to restructure it. The key thing is that a `Handler` will *not* move the work off the UI thread. In fact, it is usually used for exactly the opposite: as a way for a background thread to have something run on the UI thread.

Comment: @lumpawire - In the `Runnable` that you post to the handler, start a separate thread that calls `download1()`. When it returns, the `Runnable` should use the handler to post yet another `Runnable` to update the UI (on the UI thread).